# $mdDialog not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

`$mdDialog` not working with custom template.
here's the code:

HTML:

```html
<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="commentPrompt($event)">
  <p>button
  </p>
</md-button>
```

JS:

```js
 var app = angular.module('BetaApp', ['ngMaterial', 'firebase']);
 
    
    app.controller('SideNavController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
 $scope.commentPrompt = showDialog;
function showDialog($event){
  var parentEl = angular.element(document.body);
  $mdDialog.show({
         parent: parentEl,
         targetEvent: $event,
         templateUrl: 'comment.html',
         controller: DialogController
      });
 };
 function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.closeDialog = function() {
          $mdDialog.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

COMMENT.HTML:

```html
 <md-dialog>
<span>test
</span>
<md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">
  <p>close</p>
  </md-button>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: It seems to be working for me, could you please check [here in codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzKPbN?editors=1010), probably you missed to give `ng-controller="SideNavController"`

Comment: no i have it, $mdDialog needs ngDialog dependecy?

Comment: now i tryied using a local template and it works. but when i specify comment.html directory well, it doesen't work. But i put the directory like `templateUrl : 'comment.html'`

Comment: No you are wrong, $mdDialog needs ngMaterial dependency, where ngDiaglog needs ngDiaglog dependency

Comment: ok, i will solve this ad you did in your codepen, writing hte custom dialog in my main .html. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="commentPrompt($event)">
```

to

```
md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="showDialog($event)">
```

Comment: Its incorrect, since OP is already did `$scope.commentPrompt = showDialog;`, what he is doing is correct only